# HTML5-Javascript animation not working on Mozilla but works on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple animation for cow with HTML5 canvas. The code works for Google Chrome but does not work in Mozilla Firefox, Safari etc. My function (code) is given below:

```
function animalView(objectToMove) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.a = 0;
  (function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
  })();
  (function drawFrame() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame, canvas);
    context.save();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    this.a += 10;
    objectToMove.tail = Math.sin( this.a );
    objectToMove.draw(context);
    context.restore();
  }());
}
```

I noticed that the value of `this.a` is not being remembered when the call back function calls `function()`.

Comment: can you please create a fiddle

Comment: Replace `this.a` to a simple variable `a`, then try.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: The second argument of `requestAnimationFrame` is already deprecated. Try remove it.

Comment: I replaced this.a to a but again it not working on mozilla.

Comment: I also replaced 'window.mozRequestAnimationFrame', the problem was not solved.

Comment: Hey it is working when I replaced all this.a with a. Thanks Rohan Kumar